# C# telerik Winforms DateTimePicker Calendar Size

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, datetimepicker

Hi I'm currently working in a project that involves the use of DateTimePicker control, as the peroson in-charge of the UI of the system, I would my controls to "responsive (in web dev)" so that in any screen sizes my control will adjust to it, but until I encounter the calendar dropdown of the dateTimePIcker, in the runtime after the initialization everytime I assign a new size for the CalendarSize is not being inherit or I don't really know whats happening, so On change of window size I want my dropdown calendar to have the same width of the dateTimePicker and construct the height by a formula.
BTW: My DateTimePicker is Anchored Top, Left, Right so the width changes.
In My Code:

```
private void ResizeDateTimePicker()
    {
        int dtpCurrWidth = this.dateTimePicker.Size.Width;
        int dtpCurrHeight = dtpCurrWidth - (dtpCurrWidth / 2);
        ((Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadDateTimePickerElement)(this.dateTimePicker.GetChildAt(0))).CalendarSize = new System.Drawing.Size(dtpCurrWidth, 200);
        //I change the Calendar Size of the DateTimePicker with this code because this is how telerik change the CalendarSize in Design View
    }
```

In my Design:

```
            this.dateTimePicker.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dateTimePicker.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        this.dateTimePicker.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.dateTimePicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(79, 28);
        this.dateTimePicker.Name = "dateTimePicker";
        this.dateTimePicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(377, 37);
        this.dateTimePicker.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dateTimePicker.TabStop = false;
        this.dateTimePicker.Text = "Friday, September 7, 2012";
        this.dateTimePicker.ThemeName = "Material";
        this.dateTimePicker.SizeChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dateTimePicker_sizeChanged);
        this.dateTimePicker.Value = new System.DateTime(2012, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        ((Telerik.WinControls.Primitives.FillPrimitive)(this.dateTimePicker.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(0))).SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
        ((Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMaskedEditBoxElement)(this.dateTimePicker.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(2).GetChildAt(1))).Text = "Friday, September 7, 2012";
        ((Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBoxItem)(this.dateTimePicker.GetChildAt(0).GetChildAt(2).GetChildAt(1).GetChildAt(0))).Alignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a solution, wherein instead of modifying the size of the calendar i can just modify its min and max size like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.radDateTimePicker1.SizeChanged += RadDateTimePicker1_SizeChanged;
}

 private void RadDateTimePicker1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int width = this.radDateTimePicker1.Width;
    int height = 300;//calculate it according to your formula
    Size desiredSize = new Size(width, height);

    RadDateTimePickerCalendar cal = this.radDateTimePicker1.DateTimePickerElement.GetCurrentBehavior() as RadDateTimePickerCalendar;
    // Control popup size
    cal.DropDownMinSize = desiredSize;
    cal.DropDownMaxSize = desiredSize;
}
```

}